# Detecting click event on overlay item in android map (V2)

Tags: android, google-maps, overlayitem

Hi I am developing small android application in which I am using android map V2. I include ground overlay item in my map. So I want to detect click on overlay item. I added overlay item in following manner.

```
 LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(0, 0);

        GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                //.image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.img)
                  .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(this, markerView)))
                .position(NEWARK, 860000f, 650000f);
        GroundOverlay imageOverlay = googleMap.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
```

So I want to do something when user clicks on this overlay item. Need Some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen it via googleMap.setOnGroundOverlayClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

There are no `OnClickListener`s other than for `Marker`s.

You may want to work with `OnMapClickListener`, where you get `LatLng` and do the check for distance yourself.